# Function sequence $f_n(x)=n^{\alpha}x^3e^{-nx^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f_n(x)=n^{\alpha}x^3e^{-nx^2}$ for $x\in[0,1]$

I'm being asked for which $\alpha$ is $f_n$ pointwise convergent and for which is it uniformly. If I'm correct $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{m^{\beta}}{e^m}=0$$ which can be proven using de l'Hospital rule. So firstly we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\alpha}x^3}{e^{nx^2}}=0\Rightarrow f_n\longrightarrow f\equiv 0$$ obviously. Then for some $a\in[0,1]$$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\frac{n^{\alpha}x^3}{e^{nx^2}}|=\frac{n^{\alpha}a^3}{e^{na^2}}\xrightarrow{n\longrightarrow\infty} 0 \Rightarrow f_n \rightrightarrows f\equiv 0$$
Is that ok? There's also a question about $\alpha$ for which the following equation stands $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)\ dx = \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx $$

Second integral is $0$. My attempt (probably incorrect, but I can't find the mistake):

$$\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \frac{n^{\alpha}x^3}{e^{nx^2}}\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{n^{\alpha}t}{e^{nt}}\ dx = \\
&= \frac{n^{\alpha}}{2}\frac{-t}{ne^{nt}}\Biggr|^1_0 + \frac{n^{\alpha}}{2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{ne^{nt}}= \\
& =\frac{-n^{\alpha}}{2ne^n} + \frac{n^{\alpha}}{2}\left(\frac{-1}{n^2e^{nt}}\Biggr|^1_0\right)=\frac{-n^{\alpha-2}}{2e^n}-\frac{n^{\alpha-2}}{2e^n}+\frac{n^{\alpha}}{2}\xrightarrow{n\longrightarrow\infty} \infty
\end{align}$$

What did I do wrong? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pay attention when proving uniform continuity of $f_n(x)$ on $x\in[0,1]$. In fact

$$f'_n(x)=n^\alpha e^{-nx^2}x^2(3-2nx^2)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0,~~ x=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2n}}$$

on $[0,1]$. You can check that $x=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2n}}$ is the maximum and

$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)|=f_n(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2n}})=n^\alpha \left(\frac{3}{2n}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{3}{2}}=n^{\alpha-\frac{3}{2}}
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{3}{2}}. $$

All you need now is to study the above limit, varying $\alpha$ to check uniform continuity (which holds for $\alpha <\frac{3}{2}$). .

Comment: Sometimes I just don't think it seems. Thanks. But what about the integral?

Comment: The integral looks fine to me: you integrated by parts and collected the resulting terms; the one without $e^{-n}$ is at the origin of the question, I presume.